# Multiple Rectangle Selection in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to make a project where you can submit an image and select players from it (basically draw a resizable rectangle around them).
But I'm not sure where to begin.
Could someone please provide a tool, npm module, or article that might assist me in accomplishing this?
Something like this but all the rectangles are resizeable and draggable
[image]
Thanks

Comment: That's not hard to do with just a `<div>` or a `<canvas>` and mousedown/mousemove/mouseup events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use react shape editor
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-shape-editor/v/4.0.0-alpha.2